# Reading large files from Google Cloud Storage into Rstudio

Tags: google-cloud-storage, rstudio-server

I have a google cloud VM instance connected to a google cloud storage bucket. I am running Rstudio server and am attempting to read in some .csv datasets from the bucket as data.table (from the data.table package).
I am using the googleCloudStorageR package and am having difficulty parsing the binary data that I receive from the bucket. 
The steps are as follows:

```
raw.data <- gcs_get_object(MYFILEOBJECT) #This parses as class raw. MYFILEOBJECT is a .csv of size 3GB on the bucket.
char.data <- rawToChar(raw.data,multiple=TRUE) #This should parse to character. I use multiple=TRUE because it's a long vector. The problem is that this is extremely slow.
DT <- fread(char.data) # ultimately I am trying to read the data in as data.table.
```

This method is prohibitively slow because the parsing step (rawToChar) is very slow. Is there a better way of doing this? I have tried mounting the directory with GCS fuse, but that was also very slow.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleCloudStorageR/vignettes/googleCloudStorageR.html)`## if you want to do your own parsing, set parseObject to FALSE
## use httr::content() to parse afterwards
raw_download <- gcs_get_object(objects$name[[1]], parseObject = FALSE) `

Comment: Perhaps you can load the files into BigQuery or similar, since they are CSVs.  BigQuery accepts loads directly from Cloud Storage.